# How to find "dtype('O')" in an array of floats?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

In attempting to construct a [`csr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) from an `array`, I get this error:

```
In [83]: np.info(urt[0,0])
float(x) -> floating point number

Convert a string or number to a floating point number, if possible.

In [84]: np.info(urt)
class:  ndarray
shape:  (18586, 18586)
strides:  (148688, 8)
itemsize:  8
aligned:  True
contiguous:  True
fortran:  False
data pointer: 0xa85bf0040
byteorder:  little
byteswap:  False
type: object

In [84]: csr_matrix(urt)
...
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)
```

Presumably this is because, somewhere, in the `array` there appears [an array protocol (`dtype`) of `'O'` for `Object`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) of some kind*.

So I need to clean the data before constructing the `csr_matrix`.  Hence my question, how can I locate the `Object` in an `array` otherwise comprising `float`s?

*I don't know how an `Object` snuck into the `array` but I suspect it may be an arbitrary precision number.

Comment: have you tried just using `.astype('foat')`?

Comment: in any case, that output from `np.info` means you have *`float` objects*, i.e. the native Python `float` type, which is a full fledged object (everything in Python is an object).

Comment: The "dtype('O')" refers to the array protocol for Objects other than 'b' boolean,
'i' (signed) integer,
'u' unsigned integer,
'f' floating-point,
'c' complex-floating point,
'S', 'a' (byte-)string,
'U' Unicode & 
'V' raw data (void).  See "Array-protocol type strings" under https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: `.astype('float')` got rid of the problem, but I'd still like to know how a `dtype('O')` ended up as an element of the `ndarray`.

Comment: because you were adding `float` objects to your array, at least at position `urt[0,0]` as evidenced by your output. how that happened I could not possibly say since you haven't given us any more information.

Comment: So, what you are saying, apparently, is that there is a "`float`" that is a "`dtype('f')`" but there is also a "`float`" that is "`dtype('O')`"?  If that is the case, why did '`np.info(urt[0,0])`' not return a '`type: object`' as did '`np.info(urt)`'?  Indeed, why did it not return any '`type'` at all?

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of `numpy` and its relationship to Python. `numpy` is essentially an object-oriented wrapper around primitive, typed arrays. *Everything* in Python is an object. When your `numpy` array has a dtype "object", that means underneath the hood  it is an array of PyObject pointers. `float` objects *don't have dtypes*, `numpy.ndarray` objects have dtypes, which mostly are various primitive numerical types (although it also supports arrays of c-like structs). I can only guess as to why you've created an array that contains python `float` objects.

Comment: As to why didn't `np.info(urt[0,0])` not return `type: object'` **because the type isn't `object`, it's `float`**. Although, **everything** inherits from `object`. Honestly, I've never really used `np.info`, I would suggest sticking to the more typical introspection utilities in Python, i.e. `type`, `isinstance` etc. Note, when you access a value of a numeric-dtype array, the value will get "boxed" with a full-fledged Python object.